# What is out of box features in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What is out of box features in sharepoint. The features which we can develop through the code are know as out of box features? I am confused to know about it. I wonder if any one has an explanation.  These are new in sharpeoint 2010 or existed in WSS3.0 also?

Comment: You're asking what "out of the box" means? It means literally "out of the box" - something that's available immediately without any extra coding/development. e.g. you buy a new car, it immediately is able to take you places, out-of-the-box. but if you want fancy chrome rims or a new paint job, that'll take extra work.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, means the features which are available without our custom code right!!

Comment: Couldn't this be found on Microsoft's sharepoint site?

Comment: @canadiancreed Not clearly found.. if you found can you please give me link?

Comment: Did @MarcB answer your question?? I'm confused about what you actually wanted to know.

Comment: He didnt answered, but he gave an example. but i dont know if it is correct or not. he no more give any reply.. if you know please tell me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Out of the box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box) features available for SharePoint 2010 are clearly stated on [SharePoint site](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/Pages/Features.aspx).

Features we develop are not out of the box. They are customization or developed using the SDKs. WSS3.0 had its out of box features. The new version of WSS 3.0 is SharePoint Foundation and [here](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx) is list of features for each edition of SharePoint server.

I hope, this will clear your doubts. Out of the box just means something that comes with the product when you buy it.